# Ui Interaction - Update Textboxes with ScriptDb Values

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to load values retrieved from ScriptDb into an interface application developed within an interface built with GUI Builder. I've loaded the interface via:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
app.add(app.loadComponent("ScriptDBUi"))
```

Now that it's loaded I would like to load values into text boxes to display ScriptDb values, however when I try to use `setValue` or `setText`, I'm notified that properties can't be changed or modified.

Can you point me in the right direction to be able to interact with UI elements?

---

Here's some additional code:

```
function ReadScriptDb() {
var DB = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var Ob = DB.query({Number: "0002"}).next();
var Ui = doGet()
var TextBox = Ui.getElementById("Project")
TextBox.setText(Ob.Project)
}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("ScriptDBUi"));
  return app;
}
```

I've then published this simple script as a Web App so I can test the Ui. After publishing i'll get 1 of 2 things depending on my changes: 1 - The text block doesn't update with the value returned (..i've debugged to insure that Ob.Project is returning a string value), or I've been prompted that i cant assign or modify a value.

Thanks for any insights you can offer.

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your code that doesn't work? What are you trying to call setValue or setText on? The app itself or the component?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of the workflow is off. here's what I've done to test & learn:

Comment: Here's what I have done so far: - Created a script project, - Created simple scripts to read and write to the scriptdb, - i then built a Ui using the Gui builder, - i'm now trying to interact with the text box within that Ui.

Comment: I understand your question and the issue better now. Just edited my response below. You shouldn't call doGet again after the app launches. Instead you can get the App reference via another API call for getActiveApplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it here -

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder#extending

Your code would look something like this (untested)

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
app.add(app.loadComponent("ScriptDBUi"))
var textBox = app.getElementById("myTextBoxName");//ID you gave in the GUI builder
textBox.setText("Hello world");
```

Edit -

In a call back function you'll want to use [UiAp.getActiveApplcation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp#getActiveApplication) instead of createApplication

```
Your code should be this - 
function ReadScriptDb() {
var DB = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var Ob = DB.query({Number: "0002"}).next();
var Ui = UiApp.getActiveApplication();//CHANGED THIS
var TextBox = Ui.getElementById("Project")
TextBox.setText(Ob.Project)
}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("ScriptDBUi"));
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arun for your help. In the end I wasn't understanding for order that the code was processing. This is what did it in the end. Basically (..and rather foolishly of me) I wasn't calling ReadScriptDb because I wasn't understanding that doGet() was the entry point for my App. I passed 'app' to my ReadScriptDb function, and then back again to doGet and everything worked great. Thanks for point the way.

```
function ReadScriptDb(app) {
var DB = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var Ob = DB.query({Number: "0002"}).next();
var Project = Ob.Project;
var TextBox = app.getElementById("Project");
TextBox.setText(Project);
return app;
}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("ScriptDBUi"));
   ReadScriptDb(app)
  return app;
}
```

This reference helped clear it up for me:
[UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp)

"..The doGet function is the one that is run when a user accesses the URL at which the script is deployed.."

***Cheers***